# My MakeFile can't find my header directory

Tags: c++, makefile

This is my Makefile :

```
NAME    = pong

SRCS    = src/main.cpp

OBJS    = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

CFLAGS  += -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -I include/

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
    g++ -o $(NAME) $(SRCS) $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS)

fclean: clean
    rm -f $(NAME)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

When I do `make`, it tells me that the header I include in my main.ccp does not exist.

```
#include "prototypes.hpp"
```

This is my project organisation :

```
.
├── a.out
├── include
│   └── prototypes.hpp
├── Makefile
├── src
│   └── main.cpp
└── test
```

And the weirdest thing is that this work when I do

```
g++ -o test src/main.cpp  -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system  -I include/
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: Does make tell you actually or is it g++?

Comment: It's g++. `g++    -c -o src/main.o src/main.cpp
src/main.cpp:2:26: fatal error: prototypes.hpp: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
 #include "prototypes.hpp"
                          ^
compilation terminated.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your rule

```
$(NAME): $(OBJS)
```

the dependency on `$(OBJS)` will run `make`s implicit `℅.o : ℅.cpp` rule first, which in turn uses `$CXXFLAGS` and thus doesn't see the `-I` option.

As your rule is written, just omit the dependency on `$(OBJS)`.